# Execute console applications without creating a new console window flickering on the screen (C++, Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, console, window

I'm writing a windows application and I needs to run some console applications from it and get their output. I tried two different approaches:

1) Using _popen(command, "rt")
2) Creating a child process with redirected output (CreateProcess(), CreatePipe())

They both work but during the execution of some command a new console window is created and it's very unpleasant and ugly. Is there some way to execute the commands in background without opening a new console?

Comment: CreateProcess doesn't create a new console unless the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag is being passed in. Are you sure that the commands that you are executing are not creating their own consoles?

Comment: You are right, the commands that are executed create their own consoles because they are console applications. For example one of these applications is netstat.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [libexecstream](http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/).

It allows you to run console programs and read their output using a stream.

As stated by the website it:

- Works on Linux and Windows
- Uses threads
- Does not depend on any other non-standard library
- Is distributed as source code only, requires you to compile and link one file into your program
- Has a BSD-style [license](http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/license.html)

I may add that I've successfully used it in a recent project, and that no disgracious console window popped up.

Comment: Have you used it to run console applications?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try passing the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` or `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag to `CreateProcess`.